# What is the meaning of Microchip's acronym TRIS for data direction registers?

Tags: microchip

When reading/writing/talking about electronics, I like to understand the acronyms and mneumonics for abbreviations used for registers, functions, filenames, pin names, etc.  Usually, the first time the abbreviation is used, either the context or a parenthetical note sets it off, or it's blatantly obvious.

On the Microchip dsPIC parts, the TRIS register controls the data direction. I can't find a note which uses the full word/phrase that would be abbreviated or have the acronym TRIS. ('The Register Input/output Settting' is about the best I can come up with, although 'TRIS Really Is a Silly abbreviation' is a close second guess).

How do you remember this?  I've heard it pronounced as a word, but I'd like to know what it means to make it easier to remember, read, and write.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

TRIS stands for TRIState. It means the port is waiting for an input rather than output a high or low signal.

It's named as such because a port can have 3 states:

- Output High
- Output Low
- Input (High Impedance)

Comment: That was quick!  Do you have a source for this name (and, ideally, others I'll come across), or did it just 'click' for you?

Comment: @reemrevnivek: It's just something that I already knew... I'm not sure where I learnt it though! Probably a microchip datasheet or something.

Comment: The reason that Microchip don't spell-out the words TRI-STATE is that TRI-STATE® is a registered trademark of National Semiconductor.

Comment: @reemrevnivek: I think I learnt this when I first started learning pic assembler from this page: http://www.mstracey.btinternet.co.uk/pictutorial/progtut3.htm The code snippet second from the bottom has this comment: "which is the address of the Tri-State register for PortA"

Answer (score 2):

The term "tri-state" is often used informally to refer to the act of floating a pin; I know that National Semiconductor used to have a trademark on the term, though its widespread usage as a common term may have rendered it unenforceable.

Incidentally, in case anyone's curious why the OPTION instruction is so called, and the settings aren't controlled via a register, on the original General Instruments PIC devices, there were no TRIS or OPTION instructions; instead, the selection of which pins should be floating, as well as the settings for the timer/watchdog prescalar and modes, were part of the factory specification (the devices used mask ROM, so the whole program would be a factory spec).

Comment: National used to have a habit of registering just about every term in the English language. Some of the more dubious ones like 'National Anthem' and 'Damn Fast' have disappeared (unsurprisingly) from [their list](http://www.national.com/analog/trademark) but TRI-STATE is still there!

Comment: @MikeJ-UK: Tri-state is listed as a live trademark according to the USPTO web site, so I would certainly not recommend anyone selling chips describe the outputs as "tri-state"; the trademark may or may not be enforceable given the common generic usage, but that doesn't mean I'd want to spend the legal fees to find out.